# How can i update in firebase and skip the unmodified data in batch?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to update the array in firebase which contain some modified and unmodified objects. Now i want to skip the unmodified data to update in firebase. Please help me to do that.

Basically i am getting error

> No document to update: projects/.....

```
updatedList(previousIndex: number, previousContainerData: Card[], currentIndex: number, currentContainerData: Card[]): List[] {

    const previousList = { ...this.listItems[previousIndex] }
    const currentList = { ...this.listItems[currentIndex] }

    if (previousList && currentList) {
      previousList.cards = (previousList.cards as Card[]).filter(card => !previousContainerData.find(c => c.id === card.id));
      currentList.cards = (currentList.cards as Card[]).filter(card => !currentContainerData.find(c => c.id === card.id));

      currentList.cards.push(...previousContainerData);
      previousList.cards.push(...currentContainerData);

      previousList.cards.forEach((card, index) => {
        card.order = index + 1;
      });
      currentList.cards.forEach((card, index) => {
        card.order = index + 1;
      });
    }

    return this.listItems;
  }
```

```
this.cardService.update(this.boardId, list).pipe(
     takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe((res) => {
     console.log(res)
})
```

```
  update(boardId: string, lists: List[]): Observable<void> {
    const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch()
    lists.forEach(list => {
      const cardsCollectionRef = this.afs.collection('boards').doc(boardId).collection('list').doc(list.id).collection('cards');
      if (list.cards) {
        list.cards.forEach((card: Card) => {
          const cardRef = cardsCollectionRef.doc(card.id);
          batch.update(cardRef.ref, card);
        });
      }
    });

    return from(batch.commit())
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('Error during batch update:', error);
          // Handle the error here, potentially retry or notify the user
          return throwError(error);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          // This block will be executed regardless of success or failure
          console.log('Batch update completed');
        })
      );
  }
```

Any solution appreciated!